# How can I recover a sequence of numbers given a corrupted version of it?

Tags: random-variables, signal-processing, estimation

I have an unknown sequence of real numbers $x_i$ and a known sequence of real numbers $y_i$; $y_i$ is a corrupted version of $x_i$, i.e.,

$$y_i=x_i+n_i$$

where $n_i$ is a random number distributed according to a known probability distribution function $f(x,\boldsymbol{\theta})$, $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is known and it is the set of the parameters of the distribution; for example when $f$ is a normal distribution $\boldsymbol{\theta}=(\mu,\sigma)$, $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

Given $y_i$, $f$, $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is it possible to recover $x_i$?

**Update:**

Since the problem seems too broad (see the comments [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608433/how-can-i-recover-a-sequence-of-numbers-given-a-corrupted-version-of-it#comment3278194_1608433) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608433/how-can-i-recover-a-sequence-of-numbers-given-a-corrupted-version-of-it#comment3278402_1608433)) I would like to add the constraint that $x_i>x_{i+1},\forall{i}$.

Comment: Do you know anything about the sequence $x_i$? If we know, for instance, that it generally stays static or is monotonic or anything like that, then we can make new estimates. If we just know it's a bunch of numbers, then $y_i$ is the best guess we're going to get for $x_i$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I am interested in the general above described problem but also in some simplifications of it, like, as you say, for example the case of a monotonic sequence. Do you think I need to ask a different question for it or edit my original question?

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson I think the question is a little too general. Narrowing it to a specific distribution and/or a more specific type of sequence might make this a little more approachable.

Comment: @BenLongo I updated my question.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I updated my question.

Comment: You need a prior probability distribution for the $x_i$, you can then apply Bayes' theorem.

Comment: Are the numbers in the sequence related to each other, i.e., is it some kind of time series?  In which case approaches like the Kalman filter are standard.

Comment: Is $n$ a single value added to all $x_i$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, $n$ is a random value and each $x_i$ has its own $n$.

Answer (score 6):

How could it be ?

If there are no constraints on the $x_i$, all you know are confidence intervals of the $x_i$ around their respective $y_i$. But the exact values of the $x_i$ remain essentially unknown.

For instance, with $n$ uniformly distributed in $[-1,1]$ and $Y=\{0.5,3\}$, you can say that

- $x_0\in[-0.5,1.5]$ and $x_1\in[2,4]$ with probability $1$.
- $x_0\in[0.4,0.6]$ and $x_1\in[2.9,3.1]$ with probability $\frac1{100}$.
- ...

Adding the monotonicity constraint will somewhat modify the extent of the confidence intervals, but the $x_i$'s remain as elusive.

Comment: I don't think the OP is formulating the problem in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that $x = n$ ($n$ being unknown). Without  further assumption, no way to tell if $y$ is $0.5n+0.5n$ or  $0.7n+0.3n$. However, a whole field is dealing with producing acceptable estimates of $y$, given partial knowledge of properties on $x$ or $n$.

It is called signal (or immage) processing (subfields: filtering, smoothing, source separation). As the topic is too broad to be answered here, I am dropping a few current trends: [Bayesian modeling](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1572514), [non-linear risk estimation](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2009.2026077), [sparse approximmations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_approximation).

For further details, have a look at   [StackExchange 
Signal Processing: SE.DSP](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/). A related question is being asked and answered in [Does time series data always contain noise?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28367/are-time-series-data-always-contain-noise/28382#28382)